# Can I be notified if a question I've answered before offers a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, notifications

This is possibly in the realm of MSO, but since it's particularly applicable to this site I'm asking here.

We get a lot of answers that go out of date, particularly in oft-updated games such as Minecraft. Would it be possible to get a supercollider notification when a bounty is offered on a question I've answered before? It could be that my answer needs updating, or that I may be in a position to provide a better answer due to answering before.

It's a minor request, but something that could help deal with the backlog of outdated answers.

Comment: +1 I really like this idea. A lot of bounties placed on older questions are usually done due to answers becoming outdated, so this feature would be really useful.

Comment: The Stack Exchange folks monitor a [filter](http://s.tk/filters) for stuff like this across all the Meta's, so they should see it here.

Comment: +1 – I've answered so many Minecraft questions that I'm sure at least some of them are out of date without me knowing. This would be a really useful feature.

Comment: +1 I agree!! I would really like this feature.